# use keyword scope in included file

Tags: php, namespaces

I installed Facebook SDK v4.0.0 via Composer.

From the Getting Started instructions, I autoload the libraries using the following codes:

**require_once.php**

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

Then, here is the structure of my **index.php**:

```
<?php
require_once('require_once.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php require_once('inc/head.inc.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and for the **inc/head.inc.php**, it contains the codes which access Graph API (omitted those codes handling Facebook login):

```
<?php
$user = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
$picture = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/picture?type=small&redirect=false'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(REDIRECT_URL);
?>
```

Error shown:

> Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found in /path/to/inc/head.inc.php

which forces me to add the `use` lines at the beginning of **head.inc.php** to remove this fatal error. I expected the `use` lines are declared in `index.php` and it will be available in required files, but it isn't.

My question is, how can I avoid adding `use` lines at the beginning of all included / required files (i.e. is it possible to share the `use` lines in a common included file?)

p.s. using PHP 5.5.9

Comment: `use` statements operate at the file level so no, you can't. The only alternative is to use fully qualified class names, eg `new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session...`

Comment: good idea. Then the `use` lines can be omitted as well. Can you please make it as answer ? (p.s. hope PHP improve this `use` keyword in future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on [using namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) states:

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

This means that you can't "prepare" a child script with aliases for the classes you want it to access using only their base names. Each script must either define their own aliases (within the same file) or always use canonical class names.